# Old Cassandra Data in Apigee

Tags: apigee

Question from an on-prem perspective but also curious about the cloud.  When I delete an Org, does the data associated with it in Cassandra get deleted?  I'm talking about things like

- Bundles
- Cache data
- Key Value Maps
- Environmental Variables
- etc.

I know you can't get to it through the API, but I can't say that we definitely delete the data from Cassandra or if we leave orphan data in the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is deleted from Cassandra.  There should be no orphaned data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is deleted. (Keeping those orphaned data doesn't makes sense)